# Step to test in-app service on Android app

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing

I have written my first Android app. Now I need to test some in-app services but I cannot understand how can I do it.

I have based my code on this article: https://www.gaffga.de/implementing-in-app-billing-for-android/ to implement a premium version of my app with more features and I need to test the services before I publish it on the market.

I have added a new application on Developer Console, then I uploaded my apk file (unfinished app) and I have create a in-app product with the same ID used as the SKU on my application (I think these must be the same).

I need test it on my device (Nexus S) so I have added a new Google account on my device because I have read that I cannot use my "official" account to make this test.

Now I don't understand:

1. Did I do this right? Or do I not understand this.
2. How I can download my application from the market to test it?
3. How I can test the premium features without buy my app? (I'd like only similate it).

Comment: There is a sandbox where you can test stuff https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

Answer (score 0):

I've been following the [android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/index.html) and I've been using using android.test.purchased to simulate making in-app purchases.